# Forbidden Error when trying to read from vault hosted in kubernetes

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I am trying to configure vault with python application.
I tested it in local, It was working fine but when I move it to my kubernetes setup, it is throwing error while reading any data.
The same read script was working fine for local test.
In my code I am using

To configure and read,

```
from hvac import Client
from hvac.api.auth_methods import Kubernetes

client = Client(
    url="http://vault.vault.svc.cluster.local:8200"
    # url ="http://127.0.0.1:8200"
)

f = open('/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token')

jwt = f.read()
Kubernetes(client.adapter).login(
    role="app-kv-ro",
    jwt=jwt,
    
)
# To read from vault
read_response = client.secrets.kv.read_secret_version(path='secret-data')

test = read_response['data']['data']['test']
if test != 'vault-test':
    sys.exit('unexpected password')
    
print('Access granted!')

print(password)
```

We are using it in helm-values to get authenticate from service account

```
serviceAccount:
  create: false
  annotations: {}
  name: "vault-auth"
```

Earlier we were getting service account error but that is solved but when we try to read , it throws an error.

We try to understand but no luck.

Most of the services we are running on spring boot is working fine with vault

```
    raise exceptions.VaultError.from_status(
hvac.exceptions.Forbidden: 1 error occurred:
    * permission denied

, on get http://vault.vault.svc.cluster.local:8200/v1/secret/data/secret-data
```

We tried to set kv version to v1 and v2 but no luck